# Search rule is not working in IBM WebSphere Commerce

Tags: websphere-commerce

**Search rule is not working** in IBM WCS
I have created new search rule In the customer submit search option selected the drop box `Search Term or phrase can be exactly of the following` value given is `dryer` 
and then
In `Change Search result Order` select the radio box `Change How initial search is sorted` then selected the sort by manufacturer name in descending order

I have checked there is only one search rule for the `dryer` which I have created and all table has the data of search rule. I'm using FEP7 Aurora Store

Please advice something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the search rule in Store Preview. At the top of the store preview window, click Show Page Information. Then, in the top left corner of the search results, click Show Information.  And check there.

Make sure you are validating for the correct target(viewers) as configured